# gcc: –Wall: No such file or directory (In C)

Tags: c, gcc

The command line that I'm suppose to compile my program is:

```
gcc –Wall –o prs process.c
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
gcc: –Wall: No such file or directory
gcc: –o: No such file or directory
gcc: prs: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure that I'm in the correct directory. It works when I use `gcc process.c` and it runs perfectly.
My prof requires us to use that command line to compile, so I don't think I should change the compile command.

Comment: you copied this command from somewhere `–` should be `-`

Comment: Next time, try pasting it in a text editor like Notepad first, so that the emdash gets "converted" to a regular hyphen.

Comment: Hmm, I disagree with the close vote. I think this problem can easily be reproduced - who knows how many people, like me, copy and pasted a command into C, got the cryptic error message, and found a solution here after googling "gcc no such file or directory".

Answer (score 18):

`–` is an en dash, which GCC is interpreting as a filename.

You need to use a regular hyphen (`-`).